# How to solve the differential equation $(1+{\dot{y}}^{2})y-\dot{y}x=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation $(1+{\dot{y}}^{2})y-\dot{y}x=0$ ?

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2By%5E2)y%E2%88%92y*x%3D0

Comment: Thanks but i think you missed the dot on the 'y'

Answer (score 1):

There is no closed form of the solution $y(x)$, but the solution can be expressed on the form of implicit equation :

[image]